# grub and boot partition damaged

Tags: boot, grub2

I seem to have a damaged /boot partition and grub boot loader, I was wonder if there is a easy way to repair this ?

I was thinking of booting a Live CD and using dd to copy the boot partition from the CD to the disc partition and then re-installing grub. Do you think this approach will work ?

Comment: Exactly what is the problem you're having?

Comment: @MichaelHampton erased the boot partition

Answer (score 1):

1. Boot from Live CD
2. mount your drive onto /tmp/hdd
3. move aside your boot partition (boot_old)
4. cp -r /boot onto /tmp/hdd
5. copy latest kernel (vmlinuz*) and initrd (initrd.img*) from boot_old into the new dir
6. cd /tmp
7. for t in proc sys dev; { mount -o loop /$t hdd/$t; }
8. chroot hdd /bin/bash
9. grub-install /dev/sda # or whatever your HDD is
10. update-grub
11. exit # to get out of the chroot env
12. for t in proc sys dev; { umount hdd/$t; }
13. umount hdd
14. reboot

Answer (score 0):

No. that probably won't work. This is more what you need.
Boot from LiveCD.
create and mount /boot
Reinstall the kernel and grub packages. What distribution are you using?